# sshd issue parsing config in /etc/sshd_config.d/

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh

On Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, I'm trying to restrict SSH access, only wanting users in the `ssh` group to access servers over SSH using their private keys, and I want one `fallback` user to be able to log in using a password.

- I created config `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/test.conf` that restricts everything to public-key authentication. I would assume I can access the server with the `fallback` using a password, but it still tries to parse it for a public key; the strange part is, if I put this into `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, it works as I would expect:

  ```ini
  AllowGroups ssh
    AuthenticationMethods publickey

  Match User fallback
    PasswordAuthentication  yes
    AuthenticationMethods   password

  Match Group nomfa
    PasswordAuthentication  yes
    AuthenticationMethods   publickey
  ```

Can someone educate me on what I'm doing understanding wrong?

- `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

  ```ini
  # $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.103 2018/04/09 20:41:22 tj Exp $
    # This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

  Include                         /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf

  ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
  UsePAM                          yes

  X11Forwarding                   yes
  PrintMotd                       no
  AcceptEnv                       LANG LC_*

  Subsystem sftp                  /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
  ```

Comment: Why don’t you just use sshd_config if it works?

Comment: Because it might be overwritten with a update, as far as I understand.

Comment: Updates don't nuke server configurations. If you want to use a different configuration file you have to modify `sshd_config` in order to use an include statement so the contents of the other file. Since you have not provided your entire configuration file I can't determine what hasn't been done

Comment: I undertsand. I added the original `sshd_config` file to the post. I however already tried to move the include statement around without any success. I even tried to copy the whole `sshd_config` into the file to be included, but the ssh server wouldn't start with that.

Answer (score 0):

This will be distro-specific, there might be an `Include /etc/sshd_config.d/*` directive that is not in the right spot within `sshd_config`.  Order matters within `sshd_config` depending on what you are doing. or perhaps there is no `Include` defined in your `sshd_config` at all!

Comment: What parameters within an `sshd_config` are chronologically executed by `sshd`?

Comment: @JW0914 the issue is that it is top-down.  I've had problems with a value lower in the config value overriding a value higher up. IMHO it should give an error about duplicate config definition.

Comment: Order matters only when conflicting parameters exist, as the first obtained value for each parameter is used: `sshd` [man page](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5): "_ssh obtains configuration data from the following sources in the following order: command-line options; user's configuration file (`~/.ssh/config`); system-wide configuration file (`/etc/ssh/ssh_config`)... Since the first obtained value for each parameter is used, more host-specific declarations should be given near the beginning of the file, and general defaults at the end._"

Comment: @JW0914 good point. There is also an issue with `Match` keywords: everything below them will match so they need to go at the bottom.  This might be a problem if there is an `Include` is below a Match, not sure if that restates the Match state or not, I've not tried and the man page doesn't explicitly comment on Include under Match.

Comment: I don't have a good source for this, but it seems to work -- I've been "terminating" match blocks inside my sshd_config.d files by using "Match All" at the end of the file -- that way any subquent directives in another file won't inherit the match conditions from a file that got included before them.